# Handling Drawframecontrol

Tags: visual-c++, plugins, dll, mfc

I'm making a plug-in for a program and when faced with the options on how to create a window inside the program with the same style as the program window i opted for using the MFC classes:CDC, CRect, CPen,etc and then using DrawFrameControl i was able to design a simplified version of what i want.

The question now is: i created a close,minimize,etc buttons. But how will i add events to what i have drawn?

I searched online and haven't found a solution, that why i'm asking you guys

Thank you

Here is the code for what i've drawn so far:

```
CDC dc;
dc.Attach(hdc);
CButton but;

CBrush green(COLOR_GREEN);
CBrush white(COLOR_WHITE);
CRect rect=GetRadarArea();
CRect rect2=GetChatArea();
CPoint ptdown,ptup;

rect.bottom=rect2.top;
rect.TopLeft().x=rect.BottomRight().x-180;
//AddScreenObject (1,"Cenas",rect,true,"nice") ;

//but.Create("Undo",BS_PUSHBUTTON,rect,hdc,MYBUTTONID);
dc.FillRect(&rect,&green);

CRect rect3; //Closebutton

rect3.TopLeft().x=rect.BottomRight().x-10;
rect3.TopLeft().y=rect.TopLeft().y;
rect3.BottomRight().x=rect.BottomRight().x;
rect3.BottomRight().y=rect.TopLeft().y+10;
dc.DrawFrameControl(&rect3,DFC_CAPTION,DFCS_CAPTIONCLOSE);

CRect rect4; //Minimize button

rect4.top=rect3.top;
rect4.bottom=rect3.bottom;
rect4.TopLeft().x=rect3.TopLeft().x-10;
rect4.BottomRight().x=rect3.BottomRight().x-10;
dc.DrawFrameControl(&rect4,DFC_CAPTION,DFCS_CAPTIONMIN);


CRect rect5;
rect5.top=rect3.top;
rect5.bottom=rect3.bottom;
rect5.TopLeft().x=rect.TopLeft().x;
rect5.BottomRight().x=rect3.BottomRight().x;
dc.SetTextColor(COLOR_WHITE);
dc.DrawText("FL Changes List",rect5,DT_CENTER);

CPen    pen1 ( 0, 0.2, COLOR_WHITE) ;
dc.SelectObject(&pen1);
dc.MoveTo(rect.TopLeft().x,rect5.BottomRight().y);
dc.LineTo(rect.BottomRight().x,rect5.BottomRight().y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add message handlers for WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP. When you get a click compare the click location to the pseudo-button location(s) to determine if a button was hit.